# Changing the body Property in Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, navigationbar

I have a very simple `BottomNavigationBar`. What I'm trying to accomplish is when I go to another tab, the contents of the body property will change, i.e. every tab will have its own widgets to display. So I'm trying to change the `body` property when the index is changed but I'm unable to figure out how to do that.

Here's the main code:

```
class _MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
  HomeBody obj; //A class that returns a widget according to the index

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: obj.selectHomeBody(),
      bottomNavigationBar: MyBotNavBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

My BottomNavBar widget,

```
class _MyBotNavBarState extends State<MyBotNavBar> {
  int _curIdx = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      items: getBotNavListItems(),
      currentIndex: curIdx,
      onTap: (int index) {
        setState(() {
          _curIdx = index;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The following class should return a widget according to the index,

```
class HomeBody {
  
  final int _idx = _MyBotNavBarState().curIdx;

  Widget selectHomeBody() {

    Widget widget; //the widget that will be returned
    
   //There might be more cases
    switch (_idx) {
      case 0:
        {
          widget = getHome();
          break;
        }

      
      default:
        {
          widget = getSchool();
          break;
        }
    }
    return widget;
  }

  //defining those widgets
  Widget getHome() {
    return Center(
      child: Text("$_idx Home"),
    );
  }

  Widget getBusiness() {
    return Center(
      child: Text("$_idx Business"),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right then.
You should refer to the flutter docs first, this is a demo from the docs itself.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text('Page1'),
    Text('Page2'),
    Text('Page3'),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Page1',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Page2',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'Page3',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

so here they have created a list of widgets that you want to display `_widgetOptions` and then they have changed the value of `_selectedIndex` and re-rendered the UI to make the necessary changes.

Here is the link to that article [BottomNavigationBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html)

Comment: That's true but i was trying to do with different classes. And I dont know how to call the build function to re-render my body.